# fullCalendar Font size

Tags: jquery, fonts, size, fullcalendar, font-size

I am having issues setting the calendar font sizes to be smaller.

I have changed setting a container div font size, no effect.

I have also changed the fullCalender.css font from 1em to 0.5em and to a px size but the calendar text stays the same.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference:

```
.fc-title{
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

Comment: better use `.fc-event, .fc-event-dot` so you can take care of the background too

Answer (score 3):

1. Add the 'theme' setting in FullCalendar.

   ```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     theme: true
   });
   ```
2. Add your Custom themed CSS by editing the FullCalendar provided CSS file, http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.1/demos/cupertino/theme.css

Note: Demo is here http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.1/demos/theme.html

Answer (score 3):

I could solve that problem with the following

```css
::ng-deep body .fc {
  font-size: 12px;
```

Comment: After all of these years this is the only solution which really works for me (Angular8). However I suggest to use this instead of fixed size: font-size: 0.75em;

Answer (score 2):

This is quite the blast from the past, but I originally found this looking for a solution.

I just wanted to change the font size of the elements in the table (date headers, time sidebar). The following worked for me:

```
th.ui-widget-header {
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
```

I used opera dragonfly to find the element class (CTRL+SHIFT+i -> Hover over element), but any DOM inspector should do.

Answer (score 0):

try and use `!important` which is a CSS rule to obey that rule and ignore others.

e.g: 
in CSS:

```
.calendar{font-size: 12px !important:}
```

in jQuery:

```
$('.calendar').css('font-size','12px !important');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that but no effect. I tried it on the calendar div as well as the calendar container. I even tried to use the !important and replace the 1em font-size in the fullcalendar.css and no change.

This is very strange....

Answer (score 0):

Change general font size (fullcalendar.css) except Modals , addevent and edit event

```
body .fc { 
   font-size: 1.5em;  <--- change here for general 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have found the cause, not sure why this is causing the issue but when I didn't declare the document type as

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

it wouldn't change the font size.

Thanks

Comment: btw it's considered as not standard html to use the wrong doctype 
as each doctype behaves differently