# jquery fullcalendar How to increase the font size, or change the font family withoug breaking the layout

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, font-size, font-family

I am using Jquery FullCalendar in Wordpress and what seems to be a simple CSS change of font size is breaking the layout.

If I increase the font with this:

```
.fc-event-inner {
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

The individual containers overlap and look bad.

How to increase the font-size or use a different font without breaking the layout?

Answer (score 1):

If my thinking is correct, first you can give an height to the full-calendar which is fixed and then you can adjust font-size and other font settings.

By default, height option is unset and the calendar's height is calculated by [aspectRatio](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/aspectRatio/).

Example usage of **height**:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
height: 650 });
```

And you can also adjust **ContentHeight** of the Calendar like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
contentHeight: 600 });
```

Have a look over [FullCalendar Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

**One more idea**, you can apply theme to fullCalendar and alter the styles in *theme.css* as your wish. For this have a look over **Venkat**'s answer in the [fullCalendar Font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565799/fullcalendar-font-size).

Comment: I am using a theme, decreasing the font size per Venkat's answer does work, however increasing the font size via css breaks the layout. Could you explain further how to use your javascript options? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just write below code it will increase the text size of navi button text size.

```
$('#calendar').css('font-size', '1.2em');
```

Answer (score 0):

just add two property

```
  events: [
    {
      titleHtml: 'Ma Box',
      titleHtml_Size: '18px',
      start: '2018-05-22',
      end: '2018-06-26',
    }
  ]
```

And add this function :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({           
        eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
                if (event.titleHtml) {
                        eventElement.find("span.fc-title").prepend("<span style='font-size:"+event.titleHtml_Size+"'>" + event.titleHtml +"</span>");
                }
        },
```